# Database issues after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I get this on phpMyAdmin after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. What to do?

Deprecation Notice in ./libraries/classes/Di/ReflectorItem.php#82
Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Di/ReflectorItem.php#50: PhpMyAdmin\Di\ReflectorItem->_resolveArgs(
array,
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Di/FactoryItem.php#27: PhpMyAdmin\Di\ReflectorItem->invoke(array)
./libraries/classes/Di/Container.php#62: PhpMyAdmin\Di\FactoryItem->get(array)
./libraries/classes/Di/AliasItem.php#44: PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container->get(
string 'PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\Database\DatabaseStructureController',
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Di/Container.php#62: PhpMyAdmin\Di\AliasItem->get(array)
./db_structure.php#35: PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container->get(
string 'DatabaseStructureController',
array,
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade to phpMyAdmin 5.0

See: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu#ubnutu-ppa

No php-gettext package to install.

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phpmyadmin/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Thanks. But I disabled PHP 8.0 and enabled PHP 7.2, because on my VPS has a to much software programmed with Zend Framework 1.12.20 and that Framework is too old for PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 1):

This would be due to running an *old* version of phpMyAdmin. These functions were deprecated a few years ago when PHP7.0 came out, so you'll need to update the software.

If you installed phpMyAdmin via the command line, then you can do this:

```
sudo apt remove --purge phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-gettext php-mbstring -y
```

If you installed phpMyAdmin by downloading a .zip and dropping it in a directory, you'll need to [download an updated version from the project website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) and bring the code up to date. Given the number of bots that are actively scanning public IP addresses for older versions of phpMyAdmin to break into, it would be a good idea to always run the most recent release of the software.

Hope this resolves your issue

---

***Note:** If you have multiple versions of PHP installed on your system as a result of multiple Ubuntu upgrades over the years, then it may be a good idea to uninstall them all and pull in just the most recent version.*

1. List all installed packages with PHP:

   ```
   $ sudo apt list --installed | grep php
   ```
2. Uninstall the packages, avoiding the use of wildcards like `php*` because there's too much risk involved with wildcards
3. Install the PHP version best suited for the current operating system:

   ```
   $ sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-mbstring php-common php-xml php-json php-dev
   ```

   Be sure to include all of the PHP libraries that your system will actually need, as each installation is different.

Comment: This is not solve the problem.

Comment: And also php-gettext missing from packages.

Comment: Yes there is multiple php versions from 7.0 to 8.0. But my VPS is originally installed with Ubuntu 18.04 and ever upgraded to newer version of Ubuntu. And I need PHP 8 to my WordPress installation because it's site health-check notices about php 7.4 is risk.

Comment: This is a good solution! Please use our PPA version and it will work https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu#ubnutu-ppa